# OCI: ERROR while executing CREATE and DROP table

Tags: sql, c, oracle, oracle-call-interface

I am using C API to create and drop tables from the oracle database. The snippet of code is

```
OCIStmt *stmt;
rc = OCIHandleAlloc(ora_env, (dvoid **)&stmt, OCI_HTYPE_STMT, 0, 0);

char *query = "DROP TABLE idmap_id;";
rc = OCIStmtPrepare(stmt, errhp, (OraText*)query, strlen(query), OCI_NTV_SYNTAX, OCI_DEFAULT);
rc = OCIStmtExecute(svchp, stmt, errhp, 1, 0, NULL, NULL, OCI_DEFAULT);
```

When I run this DROP TABLE query I get following error

```
OCIStmtExecute() ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
```

When I replace the query with CREATE TABLE like this

```
char *query = "CREATE TABLE idmap_id (id varchar2(32 CHAR) NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT idmap_id_pk PRIMARY KEY (id));";
```

I get error

```
OCIStmtExecute() ORA-00922: missing or invalid option
```

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Remove the semi-colon?

Comment: oh.. thanks! it works. I normally add semi-colon in my perl code for MySQL queries. I didnt know that C will complain.

Comment: I guess it's not a C problem, rather a problem that Oracle expects another SQL statement after it.

Comment: you can add this comment to "Answers" . it worked. thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the semi-colon.

(I guess Oracle expects another SQL statement after it.)